# Special permission for Calendar API meeting invites to be in Inbox

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'm a software engineer and I'm developing a telehealth platform that allows patients and professionals have a meeting.

I use Google Workspace with domain authority delegation to create Meeting or conference, I've a problem. Anytime I create this invite, it goes straight to spam folder until the users say they recognize the sender or choose to accept invitations from this email on their Calendar.

I've fear, this is a tedious job for patients, not much for professionals because they might be asked to do this as part of the requirement to work on the platform. The patient doesn't want to be stressed doing some technical stuff.

I will like to ask if there's some special privilege available for startup or companies in certain industries like health to be legitimately verified and able to send email invitations to user and it straights away land in the inbox instead of spam.

Thank you.